# Rename Sticker Pack App Project - Bundle Display Name Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, imessage

I need to rename the Sticker Application name that is displayed under the app icon in the iMessage App Store.  I'm using XCode 8.

I have tried:
- Renaming Bundle Display Name under the Info tab of the application file inside Products
- Renaming Bundle Display Name under Custom iOS Target Properties under the application
- Remaming the Name under Identity & Type for the Project.  This forces a rename of the project files but doesn't change the name displayed under the app icon in the imessage store
- Restarting XCode 8
- Restarting Mac

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can define it in StickerPackExtension Settings (see the pic). Thats the name that will be displayed under your app icon in iMessage App selection screen.

[image]